# Restrict list to reals for statistics

Tags: assumptions

I get conjugates in output when running this:

```
Clear[X];
X:={x1,x2,x3};
Assuming[{Element[X, Reals]},StandardDeviation[X]]
```

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: There is nothing wrong. If x is real, is it not it own conjugate? And won't that observation mean that the result you see is correct?

Comment: Perhaps `Assuming[{Element[X, Reals]}, StandardDeviation[X] // Simplify]` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Simplify[StandardDeviation[X], Element[X, Reals]]
```

[image]